# Authorization Token accessing Cosmos DB document

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, azure-active-directory, azure-cosmosdb, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to login with username and password using Azure AD B2C with MSAL. After logging in, we are authenticating access token using web API which returns the resource token and after getting it we connect the DocumentClient using resource token as mentioned below, but when we try to perform the action like savedocument in Cosmos DB, facing following error

```
var Client = new DocumentClient(new System.Uri(App.accURL), resourceToken);
```

Message:

> {"Errors": ["Authorization Token doesn't present sufficient permissions to serve the request."]}
>
> ActivityId: 3360415e-b937-4061-b74d-485d44550df2,
>
> Request URI: /apps/7dc938ac-8c47-4af3-9760-5e80284624b0/services/4344f786-4b9a-4293-ab0a-d27a5ccae76a/partitions/26b66fff-1ad2-47dc-90c8-cc9ee7b0d23b/replicas/131448621059935679p: Error: ...

Answer (score 0):

> when we try to perform the action like **savedocument in cosmosDB**, facing following error. Authorization Token doesn't present **sufficient permissions** to serve the request.

AFAIK, we can associate only one permission to a specific resource for a user. And there are only two permission modes: **All** (Read, write, delete permissions) or **Read**. I would recommend you checking the `permissionMode`, `ResourceLink`, `ResourceTokenExpirySeconds` if you specified for your user have correctly configured.

You could [List Permissions for a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/list-permissions) and use [DocumentClient.ReadPermissionFeedAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.readpermissionfeedasync.aspx) for retrieving the permissions for a user. Additionally, you could refer to the related tutorials [Permissions in Azure DocumentDB](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cloud_solution_architect/2014/12/09/permissions-in-azure-documentdb/) and [Cosmos DB > Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/permissions).

If you still could not locate this issue, please updated your question with the related code for granting permission for your user and leverage [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to collect the network traces when using the `resourceToken` token for accessing resources.